# How do I create a filter to show one object before listing others?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I am using AngularJS to display information from different servers. I would like to filter the results to show a "production" category before any other category.

Here is the structure of the data I have:

```
cli: {code: "name",
   development: { type: "development",
                  servers: [array here] },
   production:  { type: "production",
                  servers: [array here] },
   training:    { type: "training",
                  servers: [array here] }
}
```

I am having trouble creating a filter to display the production servers first, with the rest following it.

My current html is

```
<tr ng-repeat="server in cli | pdFilter">
```

I have tried creating a filter to unshift the production servers into an array, and push the rest but when accessing the filter, I am not able to access the children of the client object. Here is the code I have for that:

```
App.filter('pdFilter', [function () {
    return function (cli) {
        // console.log(cli);
        // This outputs a valid object

        if (!angular.isUndefined(cli)) {
            var tempServers = [];
            for(var server in cli) {
                // console.log(cli[server]);
                // This outputs undefined
                if (angular.equals(server.type.substring(0,1), "p")) {
                    tempServers.unshift(server);
                } else {
                    tempServers.push(server);
                }
            }
            return tempServers;
        } else {
            return cli;
        }
    };
}]);
```

I'm assuming my problem is when I am looping through the fields in cli, but I'm not sure where my issue is?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a http://plnkr.co/ ? or a http://codepen.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here try this and see if it works:

```
app.filter('pdFilter', function() {
    return function( items, condition) {

    condition = condition || "production"        

    var filtered = [];

    if(items === undefined){
      return items;
    }

    angular.forEach(items, function(cli) {          
        if(condition === cli.type){
           filtered.unshift(cli);
        } else {
           filtered.push(cli);   
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

I added a second parameter to the filter so if later you need/want to filter on different conditions it is easier. then just make the html look as such:

```
<tr ng-repeat="server in cli | pdFilter:'production'">
```

In addition to this answer you could modify the original object to have the production in the beginning of the list which would then result in the needed results with out the filter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm getting the error "Error: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'cli.server.type')". Any ideas? Working on adding a Plunker right now

Comment: sorry I think I miss typed server, or rather it does not need it should be cli.type. Will edit my answer.

Comment: `if(condition === undefined || condition === '' || items === undefined)` is super clunky. Why not `if(condition && items)`. Better yet: why not define a default condition `condition = condition || 'Production';` and then all you have to check for is if items is truthy?

Comment: @AustinPray, yes that would make this answer better, I will make that edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should just put all production servers first, then add the rest later

```
// list of all server types
var types = Object.keys(cli).filter(function(typeName){ return typeof cli[typeName].servers !== 'undefined'; });

// filter production
types.splice(types.indexOf('production'), 1);

// arrays of servers not in production
var arrays = types.map(function(typeName){ return cli[typeName].servers; });

// final result, concat returns new array
return cli.production.concat.apply(this, arrays);
```

Comment: Getting the error "Error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'cli.keys()')" when using this. Is there an issue passing cli to the filter?